# Build release APK failed with some material theme error

Tags: android, flutter, release-builds

My application working well and when I try to generate build release apk it throws me error:

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/helpers-1.2.0/lib/helpers/misc.dart:127:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'window'.
      window: ui.window,
      ^^^^^^

../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:68:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  RenderView({
  ^^^^^^^^^^

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/helpers-1.2.0/lib/helpers/misc_build/build_color.dart:33:42: Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.



- 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
  Color get accent => Theme.of(_context).accentColor;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/helpers-1.2.0/lib/helpers/misc_build/build_color.dart:109:42: Error: The getter 'buttonColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'buttonColor'.
  Color get button => Theme.of(_context).buttonColor;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/mymac/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command '/Users/mymac/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           13.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: have you tried deleting build folder and build release apk again?

Comment: Yes. I have deleted the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that it is in the package `helpers`. Try updating the `helpers` package. I see there is version 1.2.3 now. So edit your `pubspec.yaml` to use that version. It looks like older versions use properties of `ThemeData` that no longer exist. The latest version fixes this.

Comment: Is there any way we can directly update helpers? I don't think there is.

Comment: @CodeHunter I literally told you how. Edit the pubspec.yaml file